# Insert Number values

Tags: sql, oracle

When inserting values into a database, and the datatype is a Number, does the Number need to be in quotation marks:

Here is the Object code:

```
create type ComputerFile_objtyp as Object (
ComputerFileNo NUMBER,
Comp_ref REF Computer_objtyp,
ComputerFileName varchar2(50),
ComputerFileSize NUMBER
)
/
```

Here is the insert code:

```
INSERT INTO ComputerFile_objtab
SELECT 1, REF(Cobj), 'C:\App1\app1.exe', 1000
FROM Computer_objtab Cobj
Where Cobj.CompNo = 1;
```

Does the code above work, or does it need to be this:

```
INSERT INTO ComputerFile_objtab
SELECT 1, REF(Cobj), 'C:\App1\app1.exe', '1000'
FROM Computer_objtab Cobj
Where Cobj.CompNo = 1;
```

(I am referring to the 'ComputerFileSize NUMBER' attribute)

I cannot actually test this out as my database is not running at the moment.

Comment: Well just wait until your database is available. Or user another database. Or look for examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, numbers should not be put between quotes in Oracle.